# select Onchange handling php

Tags: php, forms, onchange

PHP having function to get values of a form using
  **'$_POST' for 'method=post'
  '$_GET' for *'method=get'*
  '$_REQUEST' for *either/both*.** But how to handle changing value in *current form* which is **not lead to form POST or GET** , simply handling onchange functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built in HTML functionality that deals with onchange. You'll need to turn to javascript to submit the form or do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

A rather extensive thread about handling onchange evens with PHP can be found here http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76930